# Start action: Don't open page with .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

In Visual Studio 2015 with an ASP.NET MVC project, we were able to set the start action to "Don't open a page":
[image: Don't Open a Page Option Selected]

With a default .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017, the web tab isn't available. When I run my site, I just want to run IIS Express like before. Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Note that I did turn off the new Chrome debug option already (as highlighted below here):
[image: Chrome Debug Feature Disabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project `core` so `properties` and uncheck `Launch URL`, save and run it again.

Answer (score 5):

For me this was fixed by opening `launchSettings.json` under Properties and setting `launchBrowser` to false.

[image]